# What is $H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{RP}^{i-1};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I computed $H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{RP}^{i-1};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$ when $1\leq i$ in the two following ways:

I consider $H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{RP}^{i-1};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\cong H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n/\mathbb{RP}^{i-1};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$. We have $CW$-structure on $\mathbb{RP}^n/\mathbb{RP}^{i-1}$ which is given by one $0$-cell, one $i$-cell, one $(i+1)$-cell,etc. Thus I use cellular cochain $$\mathbb{Z}_{2k}\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0\cdots 0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{2k}\xrightarrow{\times (1+(-1)^{i+1})}\mathbb{Z}_{2k}\rightarrow\dots$$
Thus, $H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{RP}^{i-1};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2k}$ when $i$ is even and $H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{RP}^{i-1};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ when $i$ is odd.

However, by Hatcher (algebraic topology) P221, $$H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{RP}^{i-1};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\xleftarrow{\cong}H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{RP}^n\setminus\mathbb{RP}^{n-i};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\xrightarrow{\cong}H^i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \mathbb{R}^{n-i};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2k}$$ The first isomorphism is given by deformation retraction $\mathbb{RP}^n\setminus\mathbb{RP}^{n-i}$ retracting to $\mathbb{RP}^{i-1}$. The second isomorphism is given by excision. The result don't match with each other. I think one of them must be wrong or maybe both. Can anyone help me to figure out what happens in these calculations?